# Pass data via hyperlink in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to pass data from a database column to another page via a hyperlink in the gridview, the data i want to pass is just a load of text. this is the code i have

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="FullText" 
        DataTextFormatString="View Text" NavigateUrl="~/Abstract.aspx" 
        Target="_blank" />
```

This appears to work as far as opening up the correct page, but im unsure as to how to view the text on the new page, most help topics tell you how to pass the data to a new grid view, but i would just like to view the data within the page or a box or whatever will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my understanding is correct you just want to display the text passed as a query string to the new page, if this is correct, just read the query string and display it in a label.

In order for this to work, you need to specify the query string in the link inside your grid, your link would have to look something like;

```
~/Abstract.aspx?d=your+text
```

In your datagrid:

```
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink
                NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Abstract.aspx?d=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Id").ToString()) %>' 
                runat="server"
                Text="Product" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

In the target page you would have something like:

```
string text = string.Empty;
if (this.Request.QueryString["d"] == null)
   text = "Not found";
else
   text = Server.UrlDecode(this.Request.QueryString["d"]);

// encode the text to avoid XSS (cross-site scripting)
this.myLabel.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(text);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great post but im not sure i understand it as i cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

On the grid

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="FullText" 
    DataTextFormatString="View Text" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Abstract.aspx?ft=" +  System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("FullText").ToString() %>'
    Target="_blank" />
```

On the page you want to read the param you would have

```
string fullText = Request.QueryString["ft"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullText))
{
    fullText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fullText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass a key parameter through querystring to pull data you want to view.

If that is not what you want please make your question more explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ID in session or in query string (`Abstract.aspx?textid=1`). Read this id in page load event get data from database and display.